# Python - Get TimeZone aware First, Last day of the week based on today

Tags: python

I want to get first, last day of the week based on users current timezone. i am trying to solve but i could not find a way move forward to solve in python.here i have taken two diff timezones for example.

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
from pytz import timezone

tz1 = timezone('utc')
tz2 = timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
tz3 = timezone('America/Los_Angeles')

dt1 = datetime.now(tz=tz1)
dt2 = datetime.now(tz=tz2)
dt3 = datetime.now(tz=tz3)


start_of_week = dt1+timedelta(days=0-dt1.weekday())
end_of_week = dt1+timedelta(days=6-dt1.weekday())

print(start_of_week)
print(end_of_week)

start_of_week2 = dt2+timedelta(days=0-dt2.weekday())
end_of_week2 = dt2+timedelta(days=6-dt2.weekday())

print(start_of_week2)
print(end_of_week2)


start_of_week3 = dt3+timedelta(days=0-dt3.weekday())
end_of_week3 = dt3+timedelta(days=6-dt3.weekday())

print(start_of_week3)
print(end_of_week3)
```

Output:

```
2017-10-02 09:21:32.666920+00:00
2017-10-08 09:21:32.666920+00:00
2017-10-02 14:51:32.666920+05:30 # not right
2017-10-08 14:51:32.666920+05:30 # not right
2017-10-02 02:21:32.666920-07:00 # not right
2017-10-08 02:21:32.666920-07:00 # not right
```

I live in `Asia/kolkata` and start of the week `Oct 01 (Sunday)` and end of the week `Oct 07 (Saturday)`, what is wrong here?

Comment: So, what's the issue you're running into? Error, bad results?

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216334/python-give-start-and-end-of-week-data-from-a-given-date

Comment: above code does not return first, last day of week it only gives week number, but i am looking for possible solution in python

Comment: @chakri thanks, but its not timezone aware and days are hardcoded to timedelta

Answer (score 3):

Extending your code:

```
from datetime import datetime, date,timedelta
from pytz import timezone

tz1 = timezone('utc')
tz2 = timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
tz3 = timezone('America/Los_Angeles')

dt1 = datetime.now(tz=tz1)
dt2 = datetime.now(tz=tz2)
print(dt1)
print(dt2)

start_of_week = dt1+timedelta(days=0-dt1.weekday())
end_of_week = dt1+timedelta(days=6-dt1.weekday())

print(start_of_week)
print(end_of_week)
```

Comment: Looks good but how about making a function of it and wrap the dates around .date() +1

Answer (score 0):

I'm expanding chakris answer:

**updated** Since a week either can start or end on the same day, when you input sunday and the week start with sunday you have two options.

Maybe you can change the code to fit your needs.

```
from datetime import datetime, date,timedelta
from pytz import timezone

def week_startandend(dt_,weekstart=0):
    """Returns tuple with start date of week and end day of week."""
    index = (dt_.weekday() + (7-weekstart % 7) ) % 7

    # Calculate start and end
    start = dt_+timedelta(days=0-index)
    end  = dt_+timedelta(days=6-index)

    # if week doesnt start on the same day we can return
    if index != 0:
        return {"start":start.date(),"end":end.date()}
    # else we need to calculate the other option
    else:
        start2 = dt_+timedelta(days=-7)
        end2 = dt_
        return {"start1":start.date(),"end1":end.date(),
                "start2":start2.date(),"end2":end2.date()}

tz1 = timezone('utc')
tz2 = timezone('Asia/Kolkata')

dt1 = datetime.now(tz=tz1)
dt2 = datetime.now(tz=tz2)

print(week_startandend(dt1)) # defaults to 0
print(week_startandend(dt2,weekstart=6)) # 6 = sunday
```

Returns

```
{'start': datetime.date(2017, 10, 2), 'end': datetime.date(2017, 10, 8)}
{'start1': datetime.date(2017, 10, 8), 'end1': datetime.date(2017, 10, 14),
'start2': datetime.date(2017, 10, 1), 'end2': datetime.date(2017, 10, 8)}
```

In [352]:

Comment: @Srinivas I think you copied the wrong code. That output is not possible.

Comment: sorry i copied @chakri answer. Updated my question above.

Comment: @Srinivas Ok now you have the real problem, is this what you want? Should ofc be edited to work for all days in week