# How to get date of first day of week (Sunday) on given date on that week in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sunday is first day the week.

E.g. Today is Saturday, 9th of Feb 2019. I want the date of first day of that week which is 3rd of Feb 2019.  How can I do that in Python 3?

Also if today is 7th Feb 2019 which is Thursday, and the first of day of that week is also 3rd Feb 2019.

How can I do that in Python 3?

Thank you

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. What work have you done on this problem so far, and just where are you stuck? By the way, what are the possible years that may be input? Do you want the Gregorian calendar? What modules are allowed to be used--`datetime` or perhaps a third-party module?

Comment: 4th of Feb 2019 is a Monday.

Comment: Mark, well spot, it should be 3rd of Feb 2019 as on Sunday.  I am frustrated and wondering if there is elegant solution.  I use datetime.date.today()

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the `datetime` module.

This will yield start of the week:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

day = '09/Feb/2019'
dt = datetime.strptime(day, '%d/%b/%Y')
start = dt - timedelta(days=dt.weekday()+1)

print(start.strftime('%d/%b/%Y'))
```

Answer above modified from [this answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216334/python-give-start-and-end-of-week-data-from-a-given-date/19216386#19216386). The `datetime` module is your friend!

Comment: The 4th of Feb is a Monday because the return value of `weekday` is indexed starting on Monday.

Comment: Good catch @MarkMeyer, edited answer above to correct answer. I appended "+1" to the end of the weekend() function call.

Comment: Yeah, that now gives a Sunday, although it seems a little weird that if you start on a Sunday you don't get the same day back.

Comment: Hm, you're right. A quick conditional check to see if the inputted date is a Sunday could work. There is probably a more elegant solution, however.